# How do I resolve "The following ink tank cannot be recognized" on my Canon MP 990?

Tags: printer, canon-pixma, cartridge

I just got my cartridges refilled and the black one says "The following ink tank cannot be recognized". It won't let me print with this error. The cartridge successfully snaps and the cartridge LED turns red indicating success but I get this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Take it back and demand a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove all tanks and insert them SLOWLY one by one. That's always the solution for an similar problem on brother printers.

Answer (score 1):

Hold cartridge in a chip resetter for 6 seconds.  Works for me. I have a Canon Pixma MP610.  Sometimes I forget to hold the cartridge for 6 seconds before refilling and then I get U150 tank cannot be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, including buying new ink cartridges, with no success. I finally removed the print head and cleaned it with alcohol and that fixed the problem. See youtube video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8wHXXvO1hY